# Таблица html в изображение

Tags: html, python, изображения

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть строка, в который лежит разметка таблицы. Необходимо её (таблицу) отправить пользователю через FB-бота. Решил отправить её пользователю в виде изображения. Вопрос: как это лучше сделать?

Получилось создать таблицу в pdf файле, но вот конвертирование в картинку прошло неудачно как бы я ни старался.(читал про imagemagick - не хочу его ставить на сервер. Может есть способы обойтись без него?).

Может подкинет есть идеи в чём ещё можно создать таблицу и потом отправить её как картинку? (csv тоже не получается сохранить в картинку).

Comment: А эту таблицу в виде html возможно отобразить на сервере?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583124/7927226 - про конвертирование pdf в картинку. У себя проверил - работает.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33113918/7927226 - как я понимаю - это решение может оказаться Вам весьма полезным

Comment: Ксати, таблица простая? Я с html плохо знаком, но если там структура состоит из <tr>, в каждом из которых несколько <td>, то легко можно сделать svg с текстом из такой таблицы, и если svg не подходит, его должно быть уже совсем нетрудно сконвертировать куда-нибудь ещё

Comment: если можно получить эту таблицу в html, то с помощью библиотеки `wkhtmltox`  и php-скрипта можно это сделать. Если на сервере есть такая возможность.

Comment: wkhtmltox -   тяжелее имаджмаджика на мой взгляд, но вариант

Comment: Нет, таблицу отобразить никак. Она лежит в бд в виде разметки. По крайней мере я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Сервер у вас, как я понял, Линуксовый.....К сожалению совсем не знаю питона, но если бы передо мной поставили такую задачу, я бы поставил туда apache и средствами php покдлючался к базе и получал массив с разметкой таблицы, выводил ее в html-вид и далее `wkhtmltox` сохранял картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов с [webkit2png](https://github.com/adamn/python-webkit2png/tree/master/webkit2png). Я как-то его запускал через `subprocess` (лень было с классом в питон).

```
        with open('/tmp/email.html','w') as f:
            f.write(html.get_content())
        subprocess.call('webkit2png -x 800 800 -w 1 -o /tmp/email.png file:///tmp/email.html', shell=True)
        up =   open('/tmp/email.png','r')
```

Comment: А на линуксе это будет работать? Subprocess? Просто я с ним вообще дела ещё не имел)

Comment: И спасибо за возможное решение!)

Comment: на линуксе и работает. только иксы надо поставить. без иксов вэбкит не работает..